# how to get rid of queries in a URL using Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a few million urls that can look like:

```
www.wikipedia.com/helloworld?somekey=published_links&otherkey=1
www.wikipedia.com/helloworld?wowkey=20005
www.wikipedia.com/helloworld
```

I would like to get rid of the url queries so that they all look like:

```
www.wikipedia.com/helloworld
```

How can I do that? Is it safe to do it with regex? Should I use `parse_url` instead (Hive)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function with a concatenation of `http://` or `https://` to the existing  column and get the `HOST` and `PATH` values concatenate them to get the desired result.

```
select CONCAT(parse_url(concat('http://',col),'HOST'),
              parse_url(concat('http://',col),'PATH')
             )
from tbl
```